# 'Unpivoting' a SQL table - Updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to 'unpivot' a table, though I'm not sure what the best way of going about it, is. Additionally, the values are separated by a ';'. I've listed a sample of what I'm looking at:

​

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A;B;C;D | 01;02;03;04 | X;Y;D;E |
| 001 | A;B |  | S;T |
| 002 | C | 07 | S |

​
From that, I'm looking for a way to unpivot it, but also to keep the relations it's currently in. As in, the first value in Column_B, C, and D are tied together:
​

| Column_A | Column_B | Column_C | Column_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 | A | 01 | X |
| 000 | B | 02 | Y |
| 000 | C | 03 | D |
| 000 | D | 04 | E |
| 001 | A |  | S |
| 001 | B |  | T |

And so on. I had received some really helpful suggestions earlier, but am having a difficult time handling a use case where a column/row cell might be empty of values. The below code snippet is something I had been provided, which utilizes the pre-existing DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD function.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable 
(
    ColA varchar(3),
    ColB varchar(8000),
    ColC varchar(8000),
    ColD varchar(8000)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('000','A;B;C;D','01;02;03;04','X;Y;D;E'),
      ('001','A;B','05;06','S;T'),
      ('002','C','07','S');
GO

SELECT YT.ColA,
       DSLB.Item AS ColB,
       DSLC.Item AS ColC,
       DSLD.Item AS ColD
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColB,';') DSLB
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColC,';') DSLC
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColD,';') DSLD
WHERE DSLB.ItemNumber = DSLC.ItemNumber
  AND DSLC.ItemNumber = DSLD.ItemNumber;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD?  Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional aggregation which allows for uneven elements.

**Example**

```
Select A.Column_A
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( Select Column_B=max(case when Col='Column_B' then RetVal end)
                     ,Column_C=max(case when Col='Column_C' then RetVal end)
                     ,Column_D=max(case when Col='Column_D' then RetVal end)
                 From (
                       Select Col='Column_B',* From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON](Column_B,';')
                       Union All
                       Select Col='Column_C',* From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON](Column_C,';')
                       Union All
                       Select Col='Column_D',* From [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON](Column_D,';')
                      ) B1
                 Group By RetSeq
             ) B
```

**Results**

[image]

**The function if Interested or you can use the sequence in DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse-JSON] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(50))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
          ,RetVal = Value
     From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delimiter,'","')+'"]' )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of SQL Server you are using.  `string_split()` is available in recent versions.

You may also want to try to handle where ColB, ColC, and ColD do not have the same number of values.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ColA varchar(3),
                            ColB varchar(8000),
                            ColC varchar(8000),
                            ColD varchar(8000));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('000','A;B;C;D','01;02;03;04','X;Y;D;E'),
      ('001','A;B',NULL,'S;T'),
      ('003','A;B;X',NULL,'S;T'),
      ('004','A;B',NULL,'S;T;Z'),
      ('002','C','07','S')
;

SELECT *
FROM YourTable
;

SELECT yt.ColA
, ssB.Item as ColB
, ssC.Item as ColC
, ssD.Item as ColD

FROM YourTable yt
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT ItemNumber
    , Item
    FROM dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD](yt.ColB, ';')
  ) AS ssB
  OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT ItemNumber
     , Item
      FROM dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD](yt.ColC, ';')
      WHERE ItemNumber = ssb.ItemNumber
  ) AS ssC
  OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT ItemNumber
      , Item
      FROM dbo.[DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD](yt.ColD, ';')
      where ItemNumber = ssb.ItemNumber
  ) AS ssD
ORDER BY ColA
, ColB
;

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: `string_split` unfortunately may return items in a random order, MS says. This is why a custom splitter is required.

Comment: Ah.  Missed that.  So you should be able to replace `string_split()` in my answer with your custom function.  If your function also returns a row number, you can replace the `id` with that.

Comment: Ok.  Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tally

```
WITH tally(i) AS(
    -- very simple short tally
    select *
    from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)) t(i)
)
SELECT YT.ColA,
       DSLB.Item AS ColB,
       DSLC.Item AS ColC,
       DSLD.Item AS ColD
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     -- max number of items
     CROSS APPLY (select coalesce(max(l) + 1, 1) l
                  from (values 
                         (len(YT.ColB) - len(replace(YT.ColB,';',''))),
                         (len(YT.ColC) - len(replace(YT.ColC,';',''))),
                         (len(YT.ColD) - len(replace(YT.ColD,';','')))
                       ) t(l) 
                 )t
     CROSS APPLY (select t.i ItemNumber, s.Item
                  from (select top(t.l) i
                        from tally
                        order by i) t
                        left join dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColB,';') s ON s.ItemNumber = t.i
     ) DSLB
     CROSS APPLY (select t.i ItemNumber, s.Item
                  from (select top(t.l) i
                        from tally
                        order by i) t
                        left join dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColC,';') s ON s.ItemNumber = t.i
     
     ) DSLC
     CROSS APPLY (select t.i ItemNumber, s.Item
                  from (select top(t.l) i
                        from tally
                        order by i) t
                        left join dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(YT.ColD,';') s ON s.ItemNumber = t.i
     
     ) DSLD
WHERE DSLB.ItemNumber = DSLC.ItemNumber
  AND DSLC.ItemNumber = DSLD.ItemNumber;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Comment: Nice.  This one handles the full outer join between the values in ColB, ColC, and ColD.