# SQL Pivot multiple columns with lists of values

Tags: sql, pivot, data-manipulation, data-transform

I am trying to convert table with SQL:

| country | alpha_tag | num_tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FR | a | 1 |
| DE | b,c,d,e | 2,3,4,5 |
| PL | c,e | 3,1 |

where `country` column always takes 1 value and two other cols `alpha_tag` & `num_tag` store list of values separated by comma. The length of `alpha_tag` & `num_tag` is always the same.

The final table should be pivoted in such way that there will be unique 1 value per each variable, and from `alpha_tag` & `num_tag` cols values will be grabbed in pairs (depending on their position in list) as follows:

| country | alpha_tag | num_tag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FR | a | 1 |
| DE | b | 2 |
| DE | c | 3 |
| DE | d | 4 |
| DE | e | 5 |
| PL | c | 3 |
| PL | e | 1 |

Thanks a lot for your help & tips :)

Comment: Whats your database?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68489543/unpivoting-a-sql-table-updated/68490032#68490032

Comment: @Rezu AWS Redshift